# Reading a variable, comparing to CSV data and outputting a row

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I'm having a complete meltdown today in getting some CSV stuff to work. The complete code as it stands is below along with a cut and paste of the csv file.
What I'm attempting to do is enter a number in the shop order field that matches a number in the first column of the CSV. When this match is made that entire row prints to the large output box, part two of this will be splitting the csv fields up so data is input into the quantity and description fields, but I should probably learn to crawl first.

I cant get the csv to display in the output box and I'm not able to ascertain what is wrong or if I'm missing code.

If I remove the csv code, numbers entered into the shop order box prints to the large output box and any letters entered brings up an error box which is working well, its just this next bit thats thrown me.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
import csv
from csv import DictReader

class GUI:
def __init__(self, rootWindow):

    #variable
    sonumber = StringVar()
    result = int()

    #item1
    self.label = ttk.Label(rootWindow, text="Shop Order:")
    self.label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=(E), padx=3, pady=3)

    self.SOentry = ttk.Entry(rootWindow, width=5, background="white", textvariable = sonumber)
    self.SOentry.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=(W, E), padx=3, pady=3) 
    #item2
    self.label2 = ttk.Label(rootWindow, text="Quantity:")
    self.label2.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=(E), padx=3, pady=3)

    self.outputQty = Text(rootWindow, width=5, height=1, background="white")
    self.outputQty.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky=(W, E), padx=3, pady=3) 

    #item3
    self.label3 = ttk.Label(rootWindow, text="Description:")
    self.label3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=(E), padx=3, pady=3)

    self.outputDesc = Text(rootWindow, width=5, height=1, background="white")
    self.outputDesc.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=5, sticky=(W, E), padx=3, pady=3) 

    #output
    self.label4 = ttk.Label(rootWindow, text="Drawings:")
    self.label4.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=(N,E), padx=3, pady=3)

    self.dwgoutputbox = Text(rootWindow, width=50, height=15, background="white")
    self.dwgoutputbox.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=5, padx=3, pady=3)
    sys.stdout = TextRedirector(self.dwgoutputbox, "printdwgoutputbox") #redirects from shell to screen

    #buttons
    def DoASearch():
        try:
            print(int(sonumber.get()))
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showwarning("Fail !!", "Please enter a valid Shop Order number.")

        with open("lesspreadsheettest.csv") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                result=(row['Shop Order'])
                if sonumber == result:
                    print(row['Shop Order'], row['Part Number'], row['Description'])

    self.searchbutton = ttk.Button(rootWindow, text="Search", command=DoASearch)
    self.searchbutton.grid(row=1, column=7, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)


    def clear_text():
        self.SOentry.delete(0, 'end')

    self.clrsearchbutton = ttk.Button(rootWindow, text="Reset", command=clear_text)
    self.clrsearchbutton.grid(row=2, column=7, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
    #

    self.exitbutton = ttk.Button(rootWindow, text="Exit", command=rootWindow.destroy)
    self.exitbutton.grid(row=3, column=7, sticky=(N,W), padx=3, pady=3)


class TextRedirector(object):
def __init__(self, widget, tag="printdwgoutputbox"):
    self.widget = widget
    self.tag = tag

def write(self, str):
    self.widget.configure(state="normal")
    self.widget.insert("end", str, (self.tag,))
    self.widget.configure(state="disabled")

def main():
global label   
rootWindow = Tk()
rootWindow.title("Production Drawings")
rootWindow.geometry("575x325+600+300")
gui = GUI(rootWindow)
rootWindow.mainloop()

main()

My test csv code is
Shop Order  Part Number Description Quantity
12345   5-1841111-1 Ferrari California  1
12346   5-1841222-2 Porsche 911 2
12347   5-1841333-3 Lamborghini Aventador   3
12348   5-1841444-4 Jaguar F-Type   4
12349   5-1841555-5 Bugatti Veyron  5
```

Comment: That doesn't look like `csv` data. Does your file actually have commas in it? Can you just print the first row in your search function?

Comment: Sorry, the csv shown was cut and pasted from excel which is probably why the commas arent shown. The search code begins 'Def doasearch', I included the entire code as it stands in case someone wanted to run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sonumber` variable is a Tkinter StringVar, not a normal Python string. When you do your comparison:

```
if sonumber == result:
    print(row['Shop Order'], row['Part Number'], row['Description'])
```

you are comparing a Tkinter StringVar with a string, so it is always evaluating as False. If you use `sonumber.get()` instead, you get the actual value and you should have no problem.

Comment: Brilliant, that seems to have fixed it. Thank you @jdep, just as a follow up question, can you split the printed rows up so that Shop Order, Part number and Description print to separate output boxes ?

Comment: I'm not totally certain what you mean when you say "output boxes", but if you separate each element of your print statement you can handle them one at a time.

Comment: Thanks Jdep, I thought that might have been the case, sorry my terminology was incorrect, I was referring to 3 different text widgets that I'm using to split the output between :)

Comment: From http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm: To insert text into the widget, use the insert method and insert text at the INSERT or END indexes:
    `text.insert(END, "hello")`